# Editing shares content through LinkedIn API

Tags: linkedin-api

As a user of LinkedIn Campaign Manager I'm able to update the following in the UI:

- Name of the ad,
- Introductory text,
- Destination URL,

And within the share:

- Ad image,
- Headline,
- Description

According to your docs, [you can only edit the text of the ad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/marketing/integrations/community-management/shares/share-api#update-shares). Using your sandbox account and trying the sample request from the link above I'm getting a very strange looking error:

`"com.linkedin.restli.client.RestLiResponseException: Response status 400, serviceErrorMessage: com.linkedin.publishing.util.common.ResponseException: Editing of properties other than and WLed parameters is not allowed."`

About which I'm not able to find any information.
It allows me to post shares, but **not** edit them.

Another issue is that LinkedIn API doesn't return Draft Creatives. Is there any way to download/update drafts too?

The service is running on ASP.NET MVC5.

Code:

```cs
public class EditASingleShareService : IEditASingleShareService
{

    public async Task<string> EditASingleSharesTextAsync(ShareEditUserView share, long share_id)
    {
        ShareEditRequest shareEditRequestModel = InitializeTheShareRequestObject(share);


        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            StaticMethods.AuthorizeToken(httpClient);
            var reqUrl = $"{ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ShareEndPoint"]}/urn:li:share:{share_id}";
            ByteArrayContent byteContent = StaticMethods.CreateByteArrayContent(shareEditRequestModel);
            var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(reqUrl, byteContent);
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
            return $"The correct status code is 204. Actual response: {response.ToString()}";

        }
    }

    private static ShareEditRequest InitializeTheShareRequestObject(ShareEditUserView share)
    {
        var shareEditRequestModel = new ShareEditRequest()
        {
            patch = new Patch()
            {
                set = new Set()
                {
                    text = new Text()
                    {
                        annotations = new List<object>()
                    }
                }
            }
        };
        shareEditRequestModel.patch.set.text.text = share.Text;
        return shareEditRequestModel;
    }
}

public static void AuthorizeToken(HttpClient httpClient)
{
    string accessTkn = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AuthToken"];
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", accessTkn);
}

public static ByteArrayContent CreateByteArrayContent(object anyTypeofAdObject)
{
    var myContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(anyTypeofAdObject);
    var buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(myContent);
    var byteContent = new ByteArrayContent(buffer);
    byteContent.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    return byteContent;
}
```

Models:

```
    public class ShareEditRequest
    {
        public Patch patch { get; set; }
    }

    public class Text
    {
        public List<object> annotations { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Set
    {
        public Text text { get; set; }
    }

    public class Patch
    {
        [JsonProperty("$set")]
        public Set set { get; set; }
    }


}

public class ShareEditUserView
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Edit a single shares text (only editable field).
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="share">Share user view.</param>
    /// <param name="share_id">ID of the share</param>
    /// <returns>Response code</returns>
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> EditASingleShareAsync(ShareEditUserView share, long share_id)
    {
        return await editShare.EditASingleSharesTextAsync(share, share_id);
    }
```

Web Config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="CampaignEndPoint" value="https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCampaignsV2" />
    <add key="CreativeEndPoint" value="https://api.linkedin.com/v2/adCreativesV2" />
    <add key="ShareEndPoint" value="https://api.linkedin.com/v2/shares" />
  </appSettings>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to the problem?

Comment: Hey @sorenhk, I'm afraid I had not. LinkedIn support was not too helpful on this either. I think it's worth flagging with them, as they may prioritise it sooner than later if they have more queries regarding this problem, or at least update their docs on this...